# Why Date.now() is a non pure function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As we know a pure function doesn't depend on and doesn't modify the states of variables out of its scope. I have a clarity on these that if a function is dependent on some arguments it becomes non pure function but why is `Date.now()` or `Math.random()` called non pure function. Can someone explain me the basics behind it?

Comment: Where did you get these definitions from, and who told you / where do you read that Date.now() & Math.random() are not so called "pure" functions?

Comment: @ControlAltDel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function `Date.now()` and `Math.random()` are definitionally not pure.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244023 .

Answer (score 5):

Pure functions:

1. Do not depend on or modify external state
2. Return the same result every time for the same input

Both functions you mention violate #2 - they return different value everytime you call them.  In reality they also violate #1 since they are accessing and/or modifying global state to do their work.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is incomplete, let's see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

> a function that has the following properties:
>
> 1. Its return value is the same for the same arguments
> 2. Its evaluation has no side effects

Neither `Date.now()` nor `Math.random()` meet the 1st point of the definition, so they are not pure functions.